# How to go on a submarine tour?

Tags: adventure, hawaii, submarines

I know some companies in Hawaii and grand cayman give you 45 min submarine tours for $400

Is there a way to get a more authentic experience, like being on a sub for an entire weekend?
Or do you need to have a brother that is an ex-navy seal?

Comment: Wow, cool question, can't believe this thought hasn't occurred to me before!

Comment: http://www.incredible-adventures.com/deep_flight1.html doesn't list a price but looks like you get to drive it. I keep an eye on this site for when I can afford a flight in a Mig 29

Comment: Does this have to be Hawaii, or would you be willing to expand your search worldwide?

Comment: http://www.atlantisadventures.com/hawaii/maui/activity-detail.cfm?eventID=32 is $89 for Adults for 105 minutes, which at least is a slightly more reasonable price...

Comment: See also [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/whats-the-deepest-underwater-tour-available).

Answer (score 12):

The Navy does have programs that will allow journalists, community leaders, and other individuals to spend a great deal more time on a submarine than just a few minutes.  However, these are not exactly common, and not for a week.  For instance, [in this story, educators from Chicago were able to spend a day on a fast attack sub](http://www.csg7.navy.mil/news/2011/03/16.htm).

> On the second day, the group embarked USS Albuquerque (SSN 706) for a day-long underway period. During their brief journey, the group experienced what life is really like on a U.S. Navy fast attack submarine and sampled the culinary fare Sailors eat while at sea.

The USAF also offers flights in different aircraft to civilians under the same goodwill program.

I am not personally aware of any programs in foreign services, however it is very likely that many of the more modern all volunteer forces have similar programs to foster goodwill and a favorable public image.

Comment: Thanks. But as a common man, I guess we do not have access to these Nabvy programs..right?

Comment: Well, the teachers weren't exactly some sort of executive big wig.  Depends on what groups and associations you are part of.  A friend of mine got to go on an Aircraft Carrier for a couple days because she was part of a USO support group at DFW.

Answer (score 7):

What sort of submarine are you looking for? [travelscience.com](http://www.travelscience.com/framed_pages/main_frame/travel_library/Travel_Topics_DeepSea_Travel.htm) lists 2 tour companies that offer deep-sea submarine expeditions to the titanic, bismark or black smokers. The advenbtures.ca tour is 12 days long and will set you back ~$60.000, but im not sure how much fun it would be in such a small can:

[image]

AFAIK it takes ~2h to dive to the titanic, and 2h to get back up.