# What's the deepest underwater tour available?

Tags: factoids, where-on-earth, extreme-tourism, submarines

Clearly scuba can only get you so far, and while [we've discussed submarine tours](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/how-to-go-on-a-submarine-tour) in the past, they are just jaunts.

[image: Submarine!]

What's the deepest you can actually go as a tourist, and what about if you were somehow able to charter a vessel (like I gather [James Cameron is planning on doing](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2010/09/james-cameron-commissions-submarine-to-film-avatar-2/63179/))?

Comment: The [Titan brought tourists down to a depth of around 3,800 metres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Titan_submersible_incident), but sadly, its final journey was one way, with the passengers dying when the submarine collapsed under high water pressure.

Time will tell what this will do to other tourist businesses offering deep water tours, but I would want to be very sure that the vessel is fit for purpose.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can't tell you an exact number, but I found a more or less interesting site:

http://www.travelscience.com/framed_pages/main_frame/travel_library/Travel_Topics_DeepSea_Travel.htm

Especially the deep sea section should be what you're looking for. Especially this operator provides some deep sea tours. I couldn't find anything similar and haven't heard of it too.

When you read the description of this tour, it says that you can take some tours with a MIR submarine and it is possible that you can dive up to 6000 meters. There aren't a lot of places in the oceans that are deeper, so I can't imagine that as a tourist you will be able to find a tour that takes you any deeper.

Comment: Sadly, the link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

[Roatan Honduras of Deepsea Exploration](http://www.stanleysubmarines.com/) they will dive as deep as 2000ft and have room for two passengers.

Comment: Please add some references (links)

Comment: @user40521 here's a link: http://www.stanleysubmarines.com