# Are there any submarine group trips originating from the UK?

Tags: uk, sightseeing, sea-travel, submarines

I would like to try travelling on a submarine- are there such trips for a reasonable price?

Google results showed only this ridiculously expensive offer 
"[Sailing the seas in a luxury submarine](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/luxury/travel/25262/sailing-the-seas-in-a-luxury-submarine.html)".

By reasonable I mean open to the public to travel in a group of 20-50 persons where it would cost less than £3000.

Comment: Most submarines that are set up for longer voyages are military vessels and don't take tourists unless you want to sign up for a three year hitch.  And they don't have viewports.  Most "submarines" for tourists, with viewports (which to me is the only reason to travel that way) are not geared for more than a couple of hours and not really for deep dives.

Comment: Don't know about the UK, but in Israel there's this: http://www.coralworld.com/are/cw/yellowsube.html

Comment: I'm not sure there are sumbarine trips anywhere (that aren't less than a day with a return to the point of origin)

Comment: @CMaster A day is fine and I want to return home of course

Comment: @Ulkoma by "travelling" I'd understood you to mean a point-to-point journey. What you're asking for (a sightseeing tour in a sub) is available in lots of places, although I'm not sure if the mujrky, cold water of the UK fascilitiate it.

Comment: @CMaster I don't want to have a tour inside a stationary sub, I want to (travel) for few hours at least. I am sorry if I got you confused

Comment: [Back in 1996 and 1997 there were submarine tours in Loch Ness](http://www.invernesstours.com/), but it "was not a financial success owing to the very short season and the limited visibility in the depths of the loch". Beyond that... there are submarine tours in Bermuda, which is technically a British territory :-)... I'm afraid the poor underwater visibility and variable weather in the UK make such a tour likely to not be viable, unfortunately.

Comment: Submarine trips for 1 person in Germany: http://www.uboot-fahren.de

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest thing I can find to what you want in the UK is the [Atlantis Submarine Voyage at Legoland Windsor](http://www.legoland.co.uk/Explore/Activities/Adventure-Land/Atlantis-Submarine-Voyage/). Here you travel in a vehicle with a view underwater. However, it may disapoint you as: It is in a tank, not the sea; part of the vehicle always remains above water; the vehicle is propelled along by the track, it is not self-locomoting.

Equally, if you are interested in travelling outside of the UK, then there are many opportunities. See [for example this article on escapeartists](http://www.escapeartistes.com/2011/05/22/the-sunday-six-places-to-ride-a-submarine/), or closer to the UK than most of those, [this canary island based company](http://www.submarinesafaris.com/). I recall seeing several firms offering subs of varying sizes in the Cancun area of Mexico on a recent (2015) trip.

[This article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/england/2495725.stm) indicates a company was planning in 2002 to run tours out of the UK south coast, [but it seems that the tours never happened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alicia_%28submarine%29).

[Finally, see this question.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/how-to-go-on-a-submarine-tour)

Answer (score 2):

Also one on Gran Canaria, in the Canary Islands:

[Submarine Adventure](https://atlantidasubmarine.com)

Comment: It is not spam. There are no submarine "tours" in the UK, so the logical next step in reply to the question is to list those in nearby European countries.

Comment: Is this your company? Are you in any way affiliated to it?

Comment: No it's not my company, and I have no affiliation with it other than that I was there last weekend and tried to go on a trip on the submarine, but the weather was too rough.
I should add that it does have some bad reviews online due to being expensive and short, with not much to see. So I am not promoting it, just making folks aware that it is there.